# Disable Entity Framework DateTime Default Value

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6

In my .edmx my date field has DefaultValue set to (None) but when i create a new record 01/01/0001 value appear . Also in my SQL , there is no default value . How can disable it ????

Answer (score 3):

Make your DateTime field nullable. Which is `DateTime? MyDate {get; set;}`

Comment: i dont want to accept nulls , also when i update my model the "?" is removed because my field does not allow nulls